# FFMpeg png image sequence to lossless mp4

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, png, mp4

I have a sequence of PNG images and want to convert them to mp4 file without visible quality loss using ffmpeg

So I have a pixel-style image which is being colored over time as you see on screenshot. Source images (3 top) are good-looking and sharp. On recorded video as you see on bottom image red color is looking like it was compressed.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9eWg.png)

I've tried many options - using libx265 codec looks well but its output often not supported on devices.
Many attempts gave no results. Command i used to get current result is

```
ffmpeg -framerate 45 -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p output
```

Comment: How will the output be used?

Comment: I'm making a coloring pixels game. When full image is colored i wanna show user replay how he painted it. So output video will be used only for watching.

Comment: I also tried adding `-x264opts no-deblock` just before output filename. It didn't work as well. Hope you'll help me as I'm spending third day trying solve this

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same, convert a sequence of pngs to lossless mp4 with ffmpeg.